# Can someone help me find the bug in my solution for LeetCode 680. Valid Palindrome II - A famous Facebook Interview Question

Tags: java

I have written a 2-pointer solution in Java for **Leetcode 680. Valid Palindrome II**, a famous **Facebook interview question** that passed 460/466 tests. However, I cannot find the bug that is still hidden. Can someone help me? Thank you so much!!!

**Question:** Given a string s, return true if the s can be palindrome after deleting at most one character from it.

**My code link:**

https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-palindrome-ii/discuss/1234162/Can-someone-help-me-find-the-bug-in-it-Java-2-pointers

**My code copied here:**

```
class Solution {
    public boolean validPalindrome(String s) {
        if(s == null || s.length() <= 1) return false;
        int n = s.length();
        
        int left = 0, right = n-1;
        boolean delete = false;
        
        while(left <= right){
            if(s.charAt(left) != s.charAt(right)){
                if(delete) return false; // already delect one character
                if(s.charAt(left+1) == s.charAt(right)){
                    delete = true;
                    left++;
                }else if(s.charAt(left) == s.charAt(right-1)){
                    delete = true;
                    right --;
                }else{
                    return false; 
                }
            }
            left ++; right --;
        }
        return true;
    }    
}
```

[Picture for tests passed and unpassed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwxS6.png)

Comment: what kind of test fails? what is the issue?

Comment: Make sure you understand the tags you are using on your question. I removed some tags (pending review) that are not appropriate on this question. For example, the [debugging tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/debugging) specifically states "This tag is [...] NOT for requesting help debugging your code."

Comment: The tests are leetcode testing cases embedded in the leetcode question

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the way you detect which character to delete.

If you take this input as example (I reduced the failed test to the minimum) : `"cuucu"`, if you delete the last `'u'`, the remaining string (`"cuuc"`) is a palindrome, but your method will return `false`.

This is due to the fact that when you will first check `if (s.charAt(left + 1) == s.charAt(right))` with `left = 0` and `right = 4`, `s.charAt(1) == s.charAt(4)` (`'u'`). So, your code will arbitrarily decide to "delete" the first letter instead of the last, and the remaining string is now `"uucu"` which is not a palindrome.

Comment: Hi, thank you for noticing this question! I just have a question, since I only use (left + 1) instead of left++, I believe the string will remain "cuucu" after the first checking "if (s.charAt(left + 1) == s.charAt(right))" since my left hasn't really increment one.

Comment: Yes, `left` will not be changed by the test itself, it will be changed because the test will return `true`, and you will enter in the `if()` and call `left++` there.

Comment: I got it! Thank you so much!